# how to set up cron in ubuntu from root?

Tags: unix, ubuntu, cron

I am getting stuck to set cron in ubuntu server from root.

When i try using:-
sudo crontab -e it gives me error "no crontab for root - using an empty one
888"

Please help me out.I need to set up cron for every minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the directories in /etc/cron* to add system wide cron jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have a hello.sh in /home/username/hello.sh with the code below

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World!!!"
```

Create a file /etc/cron.d/hellocron and put the below line in it

```
* * * * * root /home/username/hello.sh
```

The cron will run /home/username/hello.sh every minute, in this example, it will print the string "Hello World!!!" every minute.